# Ca\n I use the includeSubDomains option to the HSTS header

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have a website called www.foo.com and an associated development site called dev.foo.com. My SSL certificate only covers www.foo.com. So the two addresses look like this:

http://dev.foo.com

https:www.foo.com

Can I use the **includeSubDomains** option for the HSTS header like this:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Or will that mean that dev.foo.com has to be secure too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the `includeSubDomains` option for "foo.com" applies to both "dev.foo.com" and "www.foo.com" Therefore, if you want to use the includeSubDomains option, dev.foo.com must be secure as well, otherwise a web browser will pop up an inescapable HSTS error.

Comment: I feared as much.